# Best way to communicate between controls WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have several `UserControls` that are called from a parent `Application`. In my main app I have a `ContentControl` to fill several areas on my app:

[image]

**Black area:** Main window

**Red areas:** Left and right `ContentControl`

**Blue area:** Main `ContentControl`

And the code looks for each one like this:

```
<!-- Main container ContentControl -->
    <ContentControl Name="ContentMain" Style="{StaticResource animatedContent}" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="2" Grid.RowSpan="8"  Width="Auto" Opacity="1" Background="Transparent" >
    </ContentControl>       
    <!-- Left container ContentControl -->
    <ContentControl Name="ContentLeftMenu" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="8"  Width="Auto" Opacity="1" Background="Transparent" >
    </ContentControl>
    .....
```

Each time I want to change the main content, I created on my `App` some `UserControls`. One of them (to not copy all of them) looks like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="F7Demo.Interfaces.F7AddUser"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" >
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="../Styles/F7Style.xaml" />
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid Margin="5,5,5,10" >
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="25" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="728*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="25" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="25" />
        <RowDefinition Height="35" />
        <RowDefinition Height="526*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Border 
    Opacity="0.7"
    Background="{StaticResource DarkGradient}"
    CornerRadius="15" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
        <Border.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect 
        BlurRadius="5"
        Color="#877b77"
        Opacity="100"
        ShadowDepth="5"
        Direction="-50" />
        </Border.Effect>
    </Border>
    <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Height="28" Name="labelWelcomeMessage" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" FontStretch="Expanded" />
    <TextBlock Name="textBlockMainContent" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" TextWrapping="Wrap"></TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

But each `UserControl` needs to comunicate with the others. I've searched and I found that a solution is to use `Event Aggregator`, but I haven't found any interesting manual/guide, and I'm not sure on how to send information with that.

Why I need to comunicate between user controls? The blue one (for example) has a DataGrid. Left one has an update button, so when I press on `update`, I want the datagrid to save changes on blue area. Right area receives some user info, and prints it.

Can anybody help me?

**Or any simple example will be really thanked!!**

Comment: Have you ever heard of MVVM? If you would use this approach your goal could be achieved easily.

Comment: No... can you illustrate me?

Comment: Actually I should use MVC, because of some specifications...

Comment: How about some Google using? ;o) But the main idea is to divide the application into different layers. View - only visuals and converter, ViewModel - business logic, commands, logic state, Model - the data access layer.

Comment: In a WPF application? Ok, why not. It's just another pattern, but it don't uses all the advantages of WPF.

Comment: Humm I'm making so google, but as I said, my problem is that I can't find clear information.... You mean MVC doesn't use all advantages of WPF, isn't it?

Comment: Yes. Sorry, I'm not a native speaker. Well if you're willing to learn about MVVM, you should forget your current problem, read a little bit and then try to solve it with your new knowledge. ;o)

Comment: Hummm that's ok. I'm gonna read about MVVM a little bit

Comment: But I also need to know how to do this with MVC... It's quite an important requisite in my app...

Comment: @Sonhja If you did it in MVVM, you were actually doing it in MVC as well, because MVVM is MVC (let's say it inherits from it :)

Comment: I did it only using MVC... :(

Comment: Guys, what is your opinion for this solution? http://blog.weareon.net/how-to-communicate-between-two-user-controls-using-event-aggregator/

Comment: @Sonhja I don't like it. I don't think the View is the application layer responsible for executing application logic.

Comment: So how do you suggest to separate the layers without using MVVM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve it using what is said on this post:

[EventAggregator](http://blog.weareon.net/how-to-communicate-between-two-user-controls-using-event-aggregator/)

I know this is not the best practice if we're using WPF, but for everyone who wants or should use MVC, it works ;)

Answer (score 0):

The [EventAggregator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx) is Microsoft Prism's versions of a messaging system for WPF. There are other messaging systems that work the same way, such as [MVVM Light's Messenger](http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/), or you can make your own.

But all of them work in a similar fashion. Any part of your application can broadcast a message, and any part of your application and subscribe to receive messages.

Here is the basic syntax for Microsoft Prism's `EventAggregator`:

```
// Subscribe
eventAggregator.GetEvent<UpdateDataGridMessage>().Subscribe(UpdateDataGrid);

void UpdateDataGrid()
{
    // Update DataGrid here
}

// Broadcast
eventAggregator.GetEvent<UpdateDataGridMessage>().Publish();
```

So your code behind the form containing the `DataGrid` could subscribe to receive any message of type `UpdateDataGridMessage`, and would update the `DataGrid` when it receives such a message. Then any part of your application could broadcast an `UpdateDataGridMessage` to trigger the DataGrid update, such as the code behind your "Red" sides.

Personally I found the basic syntax for the `EventAggregator` confusing at first, and annoying to use since I needed a reference to the `EventAggregator` everywhere, so I usually use a static class instead to make this simpler. If you're interested in doing something similar, I have [the code for my static class posted on my blog](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/10/09/simplifying-prisms-eventaggregator/).

(Also since you were mentioning learning MVVM in comments, I have a [Simple MVVM example on my blog](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/08/simplemvvmexample/) that you might be interested in as well. It's written specifically for people like myself that have a hard time understanding some of the more technical MVVM articles out there.)

Answer (score 0):

Let the binding of controls do the talking using an MVVM (Model->ViewModel->View) architecture and behaviors and triggers in xaml where needed.

Take your multiple controls which will reside on your view(s) (pages or windows). Your view instantiates a ViewModel which will house all the business logic which is needed to get and process data (could be shared between views if needed) by exposing objects (read classes) for consumption defined in the Model. Any exposed data either in lists or raw data will be served up (asynchronously) via INotifyPropertyChanges and lists if needed can be raw or in ObservableCollections where needed.

Your view(s) will bind it's datacontext to that ViewModel. The xaml will bind to observable collections and exposed properties. During construction of the ModelView have Tasks load the data asynchronously and let controls load themselves and process.

In the xaml enable and disable controls and buttons due to states represented on the ViewModel. Such as a button which turns itself on (IsEnabled) when a boolean on the ModelView is turned true.

By working with MVVM in an asycrhonous mode with the flexibility of visual triggers and other items your GUI process can handle the situations, really on the ViewModel with no problems.